# Different schema for same collections in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I had short time learn to mongoose so I had some question

I want to use two different schema in same collections
because sometime I want to only repairshopnumber, sometime I want to arraydata at repairshopnumber

```
var infoSchema = new models.Schema({
    productnumber: {},
    repairshopnumber: {},
    reservationtimes: [],
    currenttime: Date,
    liftposition: Number,
    user_token: String

});
var ScheduleSchema = new models.Schema({
    productnumber: {},
    repairshopnumber: Number,
    reservationtimes: [],
    currenttime: Date,
    liftposition: Number,
    user_token: String

});
var reservationinfo = models.model('reservations', infoSchema);
var reservationschedule = mongoose.model('reservations', ScheduleSchema);
```

It's be occur the error

```
/home/node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:334
      throw new mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name);
            ^
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `reservations` model once compiled.
```

How do I input that? I can't find any solution.

Comment: You are writing the same model with two differente schemas. That's the problem.

Comment: @Michelem Mongoose actually supports multiple schemas for one collection: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model . But the post owner used it incorrectly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's no possible to define two schemas for your collection. The right things is to merge all of it in one schema.

In your schemas, the only difference is the field `repairshopnumber`. To use the `array` and the `number` type, you should define the type as `Mixed` :

```
var infoSchema = new models.Schema({
    productnumber: {},
    repairshopnumber: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    reservationtimes: [],
    currenttime: Date,
    liftposition: Number,
    user_token: String
});
```

**Warning** : With this type, it is possible that number is stored in string

Comment: Thanks you, I sovle the problem

Comment: This answer is misleading.  It is possible to have multiple schemas on the same collection. Please see this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982914/5434939)