# How to declare collection name and model name in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 kind of records,

```
1)Categories,
2)Topics  and
3)Articles
```

In my mongodb, i have only 1 colection named 'categories' in which i stroe the above 3 types of documents.

For these 3 modules,i wrote 3 models(one each) in such a way like below,

```
mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);
mongoose.model('categories', TopicSchema)
mongoose.model('categories', ArticlesSchema)
```

like....mongoose.model('collection_name', Schema_name)

but when i run my code ,it throws error that

```
Cannot overwrite `categories` model once compiled.
```

If i change the above models like this,

```
mongoose.model('category','categories', CategorySchema);
mongoose.model('topics','categories', TopicSchema)
mongoose.model('articles','categories', ArticlesSchema)
```

It is creating 2 collections named topics and articles which i dont want.
This is my issue right now,can anyone suggest me help.....Thanks....

Comment: you have to define 3 models for 3 schema

Comment: Said differently, a model maps directly to _one_ document of _a_ collection. What you're trying to do here isn't possible -- since really you have _one_ model/collection in your DB that contains documents which themselves contain a type property you are using to differentiate on.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try-

```
mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema, 'categories');
mongoose.model('topics', TopicSchema, 'categories');
mongoose.model('articles', ArticlesSchema, 'categories');
```

As mentioned in docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

> Mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])
>
> Defines a model or retrieves it.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - 1st param - name <String> model name
> - 2nd param - [schema] <Schema> schema name
> - 3rd param - [collection] <String> collection name (optional, induced from model name)
> - 4th param - [skipInit] <Boolean> whether to skip initialization (defaults to false)

See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454102/3896066

Comment: "The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name" - directly from the Model docs -- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Answer (score 7):

As you stated,
When you write this,

```
mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);
mongoose.model('categories', TopicSchema);
mongoose.model('categories', ArticlesSchema);
```

The output becomes inappropriate so
do this instead,

```
mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema);
mongoose.model('topic', TopicSchema);
mongoose.model('article', ArticlesSchema);
```

Bonus tip.
Mongoose makes your collection name plural by default so change a little code if you want your collection name as you wrote.

```
mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema,'category');
mongoose.model('topic', TopicSchema,'topic');
mongoose.model('article', ArticlesSchema,'article');
```

Answer (score 4):

"The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name" - directly from the Model docs -- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongoose Discriminators (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) for that.

This article has a good and easy example of how to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-mongoose#using-mongoose-discriminators-to-store-data-in-a-single-collection.

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.model()` method takes arguments in the following order,

```
name: string,
schema: Schema, 
collection?: string, 
skipInit?: Boolean
```

**Example**:

```
mongoose.model('todoModel','todoSchema', 'todoCollection');
```